# Implementing methods with same name but different implementations in super and sub class

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, java-7

I have a superclass and subclass, and I want to be able to call a particular implementation of a method based on whether the method is being called for a superclass instance or subclass instance. I plan to have an `if` condition to check this using `instanceof` operator in Java. I am wondering if there is any other way (generics, may be?) to implement this better than having this `if` condition - which does not seem neat anyway. Also, with this approach I am having to do an unsafe type casting When I am having to convert the `obj` from `SuperClass` type to `SubClass` type. Please suggest.

```
void doSomething (SuperClass obj) {
    // Works the same way for super and sub class
    int p = obj.getX1(obj);
    int q = obj.getX2(obj);

    int implementationSpecificVariable;
    // choose behavior based on the actual class
    if (obj instanceof SuperClass) {
       implementationSpecificVariable = doForSuper(obj);
    } else if (obj instanceof SubClass) {
       implementationSpecificVariable = doForSub((SubClass) obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have to do this, it suggests your design is may be flawed to start with. Can you not have a method in `SuperClass` and override it in the `SubClass`?

Comment: Why don't you simple implement the method in class SuperClass and override it in SubClass?

Answer (score 2):

Use OOP for that!

```
class SuperClass {
    public void doSomething() { /* implementation for SuperClass */ }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    @Override
    public void doSomething() { /* implementation for SubClass */ }
}
```

Now, whenever you have a reference to either an instance of `SuperClass` or `SubClass`, calling `doSomething` on it will either invoke the first or second implementation:

```
SuperClass obj = ...; // create instance of SuperClass or SubClass
obj.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 1):

[Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29) is a feature of Object Oriented Programming (OOP) that lets you provide different implementations for various children of an object. You should, as much as possible [avoid instance of and downcasting](http://www.artima.com/interfacedesign/PreferPoly.html) when writing code and instead use polymorphism.

For Example:

```
class Parent {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("In the Parent");
    }
}

class ChildA extends Parent {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("In Child A");
    }
}

class ChildB extends Parent {
    //no method
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parent parent = new Parent();
        Parent childA = new ChildA();
        Parent childB = new ChildB();
        ChildA anotherChildA = new ChildA();
        ChildB anotherChildB = new ChildB();

        parent.method();  //In the Parent
        childA.method();  //In Child A
        childB.method();  //In the Parent
        anotherChildA.method();  //In Child A
        anotherChildB.method();  //In the Parent
    }
}
```

As you can see the execution is determined by the instance type, not the reference type. So in your example you would implement a `doFor()` method in the parent and in each child. Then in the parent's (or another class's) `doSomething()` you would simply call `this.doFor()` instead of your if/else statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the concept of Interfaces, or abstract classes. An Interface implemented in a class will let you treat and implement same name functions completely differently, I think it suits better for your case.

Search about Interfaces in Java, and about the differences about Interfaces and Abstract classes, they will be surely very handy to you someday :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is known as the "[Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)" which basically means you are selecting desired behavior at runtime.  [Here](http://www.jroller.com/cardsharp/entry/strategy_pattern_using_java_5) is an example of how to implement the pattern using interfaces:

```
public enum ShippingMethod {
    FIRST_CLASS {
        public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on USPS First class mail table
        }
    },
    FED_EX {
        public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on FedEx shipping
        }       
    },
    UPS {
        public double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles) {
            // Calculate the shipping cost based on UPS table
        }           
    };

    public abstract double getShippingCost(double weightInPounds, double distanceInMiles);
};

public class SuperClass {
  public ShippingMethod getShippingMethod() {
    return ShippingMethod.FIRST_CLASS;
  }
}

public class SubClass {
  public ShippingMethod getShippingMethod() {
    return ShippingMethod.FED_EX;
  }
}  

public class SubSubClass {
  public ShippingMethod getShippingMethod() {
    return ShippingMethod.UPS;
  }
}

public class ShippingService {
  public void shipOrder(SuperClass item) {
    double shippingCost = item.getShippingMethod().getShippingCost();
  }
  // or if you wanted to keep the service logic completely in the service, you could pass the service into the enum method call and have the strategy pick which method to execute
    double shippingCost = item.getShippingMethod().getShippingCost(this);
}
```